# How to add item in objects nested inside arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to add new items in both the field 'name' and 'breed' individually by using `dogs_info.name.push(_)` but getting an error:

> Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

I am hoping for an in-depth solution.

```
var dogs_info = [
    {
        name : "rusty",
        breed : "corgi"
    },
    {
        name: "snoopy",
        breed: "pomperian"
    },
    {
        name: "ropper",
        breed: "husky"
    },
    {
        name: "maya",
        breed: "pomsky"
    },
    {
        name: "lara",
        breed: "alskan malamute"
    }
]
```

Comment: You're trying to access the property `name` of an array, which doesn't exist... You're also trying to push into a (random?) object which is not possible, since [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) is an array method. Not sure what your goal is.

Comment: I also wonder how you're getting the error you're getting. I would expect the error to be `Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`, since `dogs_info` is definitely defined.

Answer (score 3):

`dogs_info` has no property called `name`, so `dogs_info.name` gives you `undefined`.

`dogs_info` is an array of objects. The properties on those objects are not arrays.

It sounds like you may just want to add a new entry to the array, e.g.:

```
dogs_info.push({
    name: "fido",
    breed: "wee brun dug"
});
```

---

Note that there are no "nested arrays" in your example. You have a single array, which contains objects with `name` and `breed` properties (whose values are strings).